# Registering multiple typed factories in the Castle Windsor container

Tags: castle-windsor

I am trying to register all of my typed factories in Castle Windsor using a single registration. All of my factories implement IModelFactory so I would like to be able to write something like:

```
       container.Register(Types.FromThisAssembly()
            .BasedOn<IModelFactory>()
            .AsFactory());
```

The BasedOn method returns a type BasedOnDescriptor which does not allow me to call the AsFactory() extension method.

Do I really need to register all typed factories one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.Configure(x => x.AsFactory());
```